# AT90USB162 not detected in windows

Tags: usb, avr, atmel, usb-device

I have an AT90USB162, have it set up like this:
[image]

I'm trying to program the chip using Atmel FLIP, but I can't because it's not detected.
What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please rephrase your post to ask a specific question.

Comment: Is the _RESET pin really floating in your design?

Comment: Isn't it that the default crystal is 8 MHz, not 16?

Comment: Reset pin has an internal pullup, confirmed with meter and the documentation. @AliChen I have no idea what you mean by "default"

Comment: I mean that OLIMEX development kit for AT90USB162 uses 8 MHz crystal. Before developing something for USB, one should acquire at least basic ideas how it works, at least how it starts. And USB starts with device pulling up D+ high. Does your device do it? Does the host respond with USB_RESET? Then, USB device should respond with certain frequency of bits in packets, 83.33 nS per bit. Does it? Does your crystal (and default fusing/lockbit settings/whatever) provide the 83.3 ns bit pattern?

Comment: Do you really have not a single bypass capacitor on any of three VCC pins? https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/AVR/AVR-USB-162-sch.gif

Comment: So, as I can see no one here understands what they are talking about. The schematic everyone is linking to is NOT a reference design. It's a random dev board by some random company. I've built my circuit using the actual reference design from Atmel, as well as the schematics of the Teensy. But just to make sure, I've recreated the one everyone is linking. Still not working.

Comment: Also, a 16MHz crystal is perfectly fine, check the datasheet.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pull HWB low while coming out of (power-on) reset, or else the bootloader will simply idle when it finds no valid program in flash.

Comment: Yep, +1, the reference design shows 10k-100nF RC delay on pin 13, https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/AVR/AVR-USB-162-sch.gif

Comment: I already tried pulling it low, didn't do anything.

Comment: @MátéVarga You need to pull #RESET low, then pull #HWB low, then release #RESET while HWB is still low. It is sampled once on the rising edge of #RESET. Because you rely on Power-on-Reset (POR), you need to hold #HWB low while plugging in the USB cable.